# How to send Fax attaching PDF in RingCentral in Java

Tags: java, mime-types, content-type, fax, ringcentral

We were exploring RingCentral fax for sending fax. We wanted to attach pdf docs and send it with Java code. But with RingCentral SDK I just wanted to know how do set the MIME type or content type in the code. Any example will be helpful.

I tried:

```cs
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(); 
attachment.fileName = "c:\\ testRun.pdf";
```

Is there any way to set the document MIME type?

Answer (score 1):

If you can check the sample document here, `attachment.contentType` is for setting the document content type: https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/messaging/fax/sending-faxes

```
Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
attachment.fileName = "testRun.pdf";
attachment.contentType = "application/pdf";
```